# Just starting with react and i am stuck at a Point

Tags: reactjs

```
import { people } from "./data.js";
import { getImageUrl } from "./utils.js";

export default function List() {
  const chemists = people.filter((person) => person.profession === "chemist");
  const everyoneElse = people.filter(
    (person) => person.profession !== "chemist"
  );
  return (
    <article>
      <h1>Scientists</h1>
      <h2>Chemists</h2>
      <ul>
        {chemists.map((person) => (
          <li key={person.id}>
            <img src={getImageUrl(person)} alt={person.name} />
            <p>
              <b>{person.name}:</b>
              {" " + person.profession + " "}
              known for {person.accomplishment}
            </p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <h2>Everyone Else</h2>
      <ul>
        {everyoneElse.map((person) => (
          <ListItem person={person} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </article>
  );
}
function ListItem(person) {
  console.log(person);
  return (
    <li key={person.id}>
      <img src={getImageUrl(person)} alt={person.name} />
      <p>
        <b>{person.name}:</b>
        {" " + person.profession + " "}
        known for {person.accomplishment}
      </p>
    </li>
  );
}
```

**The First List is Rendered but the second list is showing udefined**
Please guide me where i am wrong

Tried to render the two list using diffrent method but the second list is failing can someone guide me where i am wrong

Comment: What is showing `undefined`? Is it the log that you're performing? Or it is the content that appears on your screen that shows `undefined`? Or are you getting an error?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the way the `Person` object is passed to the `ListItem` component. Passing `props` to a component makes them accessible as objects. However, the `ListItem` function tries to access the person directly as if it were an `object`, which may be causing the problem.

This issue can be resolved by restructuring how `props` are passed to the `ListItem` component.

Update ListItem component:

```
function ListItem({ person }) {
  console.log(person);
  return (
    <li key={person.id}>
      <img src={getImageUrl(person)} alt={person.name} />
      <p>
        <b>{person.name}:</b>
        {" " + person.profession + " "}
        known for {person.accomplishment}
      </p>
    </li>
  );
}
```

`{person}` in the function's parameter list uses structuring to extract the person property from the `prop` object. This way you can access the `Person` object correctly inside the `ListItem` component.

Comment: Glad, it was helpful. 